# R indexing a data frame using values in the column of another

Tags: r

I have a data frame, and two of the columns are indices for another data fame. I want to add a column to the first by indexing the second, but just calling the column names isn't working. For example, if the first data frame is :

```
...  Gene    CellLine ...
     KRAS    HELA     ...
     BRCA1   T24      ...
```

and my second dataframe looks like

```
        KRAS   BRCA1 ...
HELA    5      3
T24     2      1
...
```

I want the output to look like

```
...  Gene   CellLine   Dependency ...
     KRAS   HELA       5          ...
     BRCA1  T24        1          ...
```

without having to loop through the lines because the first data frame is massive. That is, is there any function or package that would do the equivalent to

```
for (i in rownames(table1)){
  table1[i, dependency] <- ifelse(table1[i,"Gene"] %in% rownames(table2) & table1[i,"CellLine"] %in% colnames(table2), table2[table1[i,"Gene"],table1[i,"CellLine"]], NA)
}
```

but faster?

Thanks!

Comment: [Reshape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) your second data frame from wide to long format and then [join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right) on Gene and CellLine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is vectorized, it creates an index matrix with the two columns from `df1` and uses it to extract the required values from `df2`.

```
inx <- as.matrix(df1[c("CellLine", "Gene")])
df1$Dependency <- df2[inx]

df1
#   Gene CellLine Dependency
#1  KRAS     HELA          5
#2 BRCA1      T24          1
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
Gene    CellLine 
KRAS    HELA
BRCA1   T24 
", header = TRUE)

df2 <- read.table(text = "
        KRAS   BRCA1
HELA    5      3
T24     2      1
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Works great, thanks. For anyone who wants to add the ifelse condition, I just separated the table1 into rows that had values in the table2 index and those that didn't, and did roughly : df1_no_dependency$dependency <- NA and df1_w_dependency$dependency <- df2[inx] and then rbind(df1_no_dependency, df1_w_dependency)

Comment: @KamranElahi If your first data.frame is massive, then this solution is about as fast as it gets. Unlike `ifelse`, a notoriously slow function. The drawback is the extra object needed, consuming more memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach. The data used is next:

```
#Data
df1 <- structure(list(Gene = c("KRAS", "BRCA1"), CellLine = c("HELA", 
"T24")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
df2 <- structure(list(id = c("HELA", "T24"), KRAS = c(5L, 2L), BRCA1 = c(3L, 
1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Then the code, you can `melt` and `merge` data:

```
library(reshape)
#Melt df2 
Melted <- melt(df2,id.vars = 'id')
#Now merge
Merged <- merge(df1,Melted,by.x=c('Gene','CellLine'),by.y=c('variable','id'),all.x=T)
```

The result would be next:

```
   Gene CellLine value
1 BRCA1      T24     1
2  KRAS     HELA     5
```